# I have a PHP script to send emails with this code-

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this PHP code to send emails.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $subject = $_POST['sub'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$_POST['name']."<".$_POST['from'].">";

    $send = mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);

    if ($send) {
        echo "<p id='success'>✔️  $to</p>";
    }else{
        echo "<p id='error'>❌  $to</p>";
    }
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

I want to integrate it with the following form.

```
<form>


  <input id="input-1" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" required autofocus />
  <label for="input-1">
    <span class="label-text">Full Name</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
    <div class="signup-button-trigger">Sign Up</div>
  </label>
  <input id="input-2" type="text" placeholder="john" required />
  <label for="input-2">
    <span class="label-text">Username</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
  </label>
  <input id="input-3" type="email" placeholder="email@address.com" required />
  <label for="input-3">
    <span class="label-text">Email</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
  </label>
  <input id="input-4" type="text" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;" required />
  <label for="input-4">
    <span class="label-text">Password</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
  </label>
  <input id="input-5" type="text" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;" required />
  <label for="input-5">
    <span class="label-text">Confirm Password</span>
    <span class="nav-dot"></span>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Create Your Account</button>
  <p class="tip">Press Tab</p>
  <div class="signup-button">Sign Up</div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to make it work. I want to use the PHP `GET` method. Is this possible? How would I get around doing that?
I want to send a PHP GET request, which would then send the email. Do I have to change anything in the form? In the PHP?

Comment: Do you want to send form data to the PHP file?

Comment: Why you want use GET? second where is ajax code(that's where you must change for use GET method)?

Comment: "I want to use the PHP GET method. Is this possible"...why? All your PHP code looks for POST variables! e.g. $_POST["to"] etc. POST is usually better for form submission anyway. Using GET for that can introduce various unnecessary problems, and doesn't give you any advantages. `<form method="POST">` will enable the form to be submitted via POST. Also you don't have any form field called "ajax", and your form doesn't have a proper submit button, and your inputs don't have `name` attribute, which prevents their values being sent to the server. So you need to sort those things out as well.

Comment: I suggest maybe you should study a PHP/HTML forms tutorial to get the basics right, there are plenty available online

Comment: Thanks ADyson. I  made a mistake. I really mean POST method.